# how to make master detail page as root page?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have master detail page,on click in page A(master detail page) navigate  to -> page B then to ->Page C .from page c ,i have to go to page A,i used PopAsyncRootpage() for achieving this .
my issue is when the user is using application for the first time my rootpage will be login page.so,PopAsyncRootpage() will make nagivation  to login page not to Page A from Page C.
but,once logged and the user closed application without logout,and he again open the application then the rootpage will be pageA,then PopAsyncRootpage() will navigate  to pageA from Page C.

the problem canbe solved if i can set PageA as rootpage once logged..how will do this?
or please help .. how can i navigate to page A from page C..(pageA is master detail page),
also once logged i have popout login page from stack and push masterdetailpage(pageA)

```
 await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the `MainPage` to your MasterDetail.

Example, in `App.xaml.cs`:

```
MainPage = new YourMasterDetail();
```

Or from another Page

```
Application.Current.MainPage = new YourMasterDetail();
```

Comment: thanks alot..it worked..Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); is called once login done.now PopAsyncRootpage() is  navigating to pageA perfectly.thanks again